# How to MSDeploy a built website package to a virgin IIS website

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, msdeploy

I am trying to automate our build/deployment process.

So far I am using:

- a Visual Studio 2010 solution with a main **Web Application** project (and dependent projects)
- **MSBuild**
- **MSDeploy**
- **CruiseControl.Net**

So after much wrangling and gnashing of teeth, I now have CCNet kicking off an **MSBuild** script to build, package and deploy the website. The **MSBuild** script is below:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="Build"> 
    <MSBuild Projects="$(CCNetWorkingDirectory)\src\Product.sln"
                    Targets="Clean;Rebuild"
                    Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)"
    />
</Target>

<!--<Target Name="Test" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(CCNetWorkingDirectory)\src\Product.Web.Tests\Product.Web.Tests.csproj"
                    Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);OutputPath=$(CCNetArtifactDirectory)\Tests\" />
    <Exec Command="$(MSTestPath) /testcontainer:$(CCNetArtifactDirectory)\Tests\Product.Web.Tests.dll /runconfig:$(CCNetWorkingDirectory)\src\Local.testsettings" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>-->

<Target Name="Package" DependsOnTargets="Build"> 
    <MSBuild Projects="$(CCNetWorkingDirectory)\src\Product.Web\Product.Web.csproj"
                    Targets="Package"
                    Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);PackageLocation=$(PackageDir)\Product.zip"
    />
</Target>

<Target Name="Deploy" DependsOnTargets="Package">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSDeployPath)&quot; -source:package='$(PackageDir)\Product.zip' -dest:auto,computerName='$(MSDeployComputerName)',includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -setParamFile:$(PackageDir)\Product.SetParameters.xml" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
```

This all works fine as long as on the target machine there is already a website configured in IIS. This doesn't need to be an existing "real" site (it could just be a shell).

While this is great, I really want MSDeploy to automatically create the website, as it seems it can do with a web app. Is this possible? And if so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure MSDeploy can't do that.  One thing I have done in the past is have an Exec task call appcmd.exe to tear down/build up a new web site.  The [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) have some web site capabilities as well as the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.1.0/index.html).

Comment: This is also what I've found - I used msdeploy -verb:sync -source:runCommand=c:\mycommand.bat,computername=MyServer -dest:auto, where mycommand.bat contains the appcmd.exe commands to create the new site in IIS

Answer (score 10):

MSDeploy has the capability, you just have to hook the right provider.

For example, you are using the "**auto**" provider in your destination, which basically says the destination is going to be the same as (or compatible with) the source, which you are setting up as a package.  Since a package does not specify its hosting environment, msdeploy isn't going to try to do anything with it, it just going to copy files from the package basically.

You are calling auto in (the *"-dest: auto"*):

```
-dest:auto,computerName='$(MSDeployComputerName)'
```

To get msdeploy to create the site, you need to use a more specific provider which understand the concepts of a "site" and an "app" and how they can use the package as the contents of a website element.

I haven't done this in awhile, so I don't want to lay out specifics (as I'll prob steer you wrong), but take a look at the MSDN document on msdeploy providers.

1st look at **auto**, your current setting. Then take a look at **iisApp** and **appHostconfig**.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569040(WS.10).aspx

I believe one of those 2 will create the site/app for you if used correctly, and will give you the result you need.

Comment: appHostConfig can copy an IIS configuration to a new site on the target server, but I don't think it can create a new site from scratch on the target server without having a source to copy from.

Comment: yeah, at the time I couldn't remember so I listed both iisApp and appHostConfig.  iisApp provider hooks createApp provider, which should create the site